# Command or event forwarding

Tags: wpf

Is it possible in WPF to relay a command to another element?

Example:

I have a button inside a ListBoxItem. The button is not active.
When the mouse is down on the ListBoxItem the button is activated and all the mouse event should be relayed to the button. (this translates to the button being clicked with just one gesture)

This is not a real example so i don't need 'i would face the problem that way' kind of response: i need to know if relay is possible.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Both ListBoxItem AND the Button should handle the same event

Comment: Commands automatically relay down the tree. They route down to the control via the PreviewXXX events and if not handled by the target control they bubble up via the XXX events. XXX is placeholder for "MouseDown" for example.

Comment: @Both ListBoxItem AND the Button should handle the same event. Here you say 'if not handled'

Comment: so spy on the event on the outer control via the Preview-event without flagging it as handled. The inner control can then handle the event via its normal event handler to stop bubbling up.